# Getting error while calculating the sun od datetime

Tags: sql

```
SELECT *, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY checktime)RN 
INTO   XYZZ
FROM   test 
where  checktime>='2013-08-14 00:00:00.000' 
  and  checktime<='2013-08-14     23:00:00.000'
```

........1

```
SELECT t1.*, 
  ( t2.checktime - t1.checktime) as w
FROM   XYZZ t1 
LEFT JOIN XYZZ t2 ON t1.RN = t2.RN - 1
union all
select null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
  Convert(varchar(10),sum(DatePart(hh,w)))+':'+
  Convert(varchar(10),sum(DatePart(mi,W)))
From XYZZ
```

...2

1. is working fine, but 2 is not working

I am executing this query in sql and i am getting thsis error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 Invalid column name 'w'. Msg 207,
>   Level 16, State 1, Line 11 Invalid column name 'W'.

Comment: No i dont have that why i wrote  ( t2.checktime - t1.checktime) as w to calculate the difference of two column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that that way, you can't reference an alias in the second query after the `UNION ALL` they are treated individually, but you can do this instead:

```
SELECT t1.*, (t2.checktime - t1.checktime) as w
FROM   XYZZ t1 
LEFT JOIN XYZZ t2 ON t1.RN = t2.RN - 1
UNION ALL
SELECT null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
  Convert(varchar(10),sum(DatePart(hh,w)))+':'+
  Convert(varchar(10),sum(DatePart(mi,W)))
From
(
    SELECT t1.*, (t2.checktime - t1.checktime) as w
    FROM   XYZZ t1 
    LEFT JOIN XYZZ t2 ON t1.RN = t2.RN - 1
) AS t;
```

OR

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT t1.*, (t2.checktime - t1.checktime) as w
    FROM   XYZZ t1 
    LEFT JOIN XYZZ t2 ON t1.RN = t2.RN - 1
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
  Convert(varchar(10),sum(DatePart(hh,w)))+':'+
  Convert(varchar(10),sum(DatePart(mi,W)))
FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: @user2742150 - You have to ensure that the selected columns in the first one are from the same data type of the corresponding columns selected from the query after the `UNION ALL` query.

Comment: @user2742150 - But, the last column `Convert(varchar(10),sum(DatePart(hh,w)))+':'+
  Convert(varchar(10),sum(DatePart(mi,W)))` in the second query is of data type varchar, then the last one in the first query must be varchar, or convert the other to datetime instead, the have to be of the same data type.

Comment: @user2742150 - instead `(t2.checktime - t1.checktime) as w` in the first one, try `CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), (t2.checktime - t1.checktime)) as w`

Comment: ya its comming but like this Jan  1 1900 12:02AM

Comment: Jan  1 1900 12:02AM
Jan  1 1900 12:23AM
Jan  1 1900 12:36AM
Jan  1 1900 12:03AM
Jan  1 1900  1:23AM
Jan  1 1900 12:04AM
Jan  1 1900 12:02AM
Jan  1 1900 12:05AM
Jan  1 1900 12:01AM this is the date at w , now i want to calculate the sum of this....

Comment: @user2742150 - What do you mean by the sum of datetime? datetime values can't be summed? Is it the correct results you are looking for? If the format of date time is the only thing, you can change it by using the modifiers in the convert function see this page: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: @user2742150 - I don't know really what do you mean, you can start a new question in that subject but put all the details and all your questions.

Comment: UNION ALL
SELECT null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,
  Convert(varchar(10),sum(DatePart(hh,w)))+':'+
  Convert(varchar(10),sum(DatePart(mi,W))) this is to calculate the total hours...

Comment: @user2742150 But why do you want to put them in one query, where as all the other columns in the second query are selected with `null` values, why didn't you select them in the same query?

Comment: Bcoz i want to fecth this data and display in listview all at same time

Comment: @user2742150 - Why not just selecting them in the same query like this `SELECT t1.*, (t2.checktime - t1.checktime) as w, Convert(varchar(10),sum(DatePart(hh,w)))+':'+
  Convert(varchar(10),sum(DatePart(mi,W)))
    FROM   XYZZ t1 
    LEFT JOIN XYZZ t2 ON t1.RN = t2.RN - 1`

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'w'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'W'.

Comment: @user2742150 - It should be like this: `SELECT t1.*, 
Convert(varchar(10),sum(DatePart(hh,w)))+':'+
  Convert(varchar(10),sum(DatePart(mi,W)))
From
(
    SELECT t1.*, (t2.checktime - t1.checktime) as w
    FROM   XYZZ t1 
    LEFT JOIN XYZZ t2 ON t1.RN = t2.RN - 1
) AS t;`

Comment: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'w'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'w'.